# firebase_analytics crashes Flutter Web app when not loaded / blocked by ad blocker

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

My Flutter Web app crashes when the user has an ad blocker enabled that blocks `firebase-analytics.js`. I am just left with a blank page.

This is the error I receive:

```
top_level.dart.lib.js:110 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dart.global.firebase.analytics is not a function
    at Object.analytics$ [as analytics] (top_level.dart.lib.js:110)
    at new firebase_analytics_web.FirebaseAnalyticsWeb.new (:7357/packages/firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart.lib.js:56)
    at Function.registerWith (:7357/packages/firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart.lib.js:19)
    at Object.registerPlugins (:7357/packages/triage/generated_plugin_registrant.dart.lib.js:13)
    at main (:7357/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:29)
```

I am using the following version of the [`firebase_analytics` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics/versions/7.1.1):

```yaml
firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

This occurs because the [`firebase` package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase) (which is used by `firebase_analytics_web`) relies on the `firebase.analytics()` function existing **in JS**. See [the related piece of code](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/blob/d95425f9ce2c874b2894bafc5081c85aafe04ce8/firebase/lib/src/top_level.dart#L166).
Consequently, when an ad blocker blocks loading of `firebase-analytics.js`, this piece of code will throw, which in turn crashes the whole Flutter Web initialization.

#### Solution

We can create a **mock** of `firebase.analytics()` to solve this problem. Note that in `firebase_analytics_web`, [the `firebase.analytics()` function is **only called once**](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6544551ff3ac5665086385aa24f1ff4020a8ca55/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics_web/lib/firebase_analytics_web.dart#L12) and then stored in an instance. This is why our mock has to ensure to somehow call `firebase.analytics()` in JS again if we want to be able to load in the `firebase-analytics.js` library at a later point in time.

Here is a script that you can insert in your `<body>` after loading at least `firebase-app.js`. This is useful if you adhere to GDPR for example and **asynchronously** load Firebase analytics (say after the user consented via Google Tag Manager). Anyway, here is a mock that completely fixes the problem **and** allows loading Firebase Analytics at a later point:

```html
<!--
  We need to create a mock for Firebase Analytics that ensures that it *does not matter **when***
  the JS library is loaded. This is because Google Tag Manager will load firebase-analytics.js
  and this 1. happens asynchronously and 2. only after the user consented.
  The firebase.dart Dart library will crash if the firebase.analytics object does not exist,
  which is why this is absolutely crucial for starting the app.
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66589887/6509751
-->
<script>
  // This mock ensures that if the firebase_analytics Flutter plugin uses this mock as its
  // instance (which does not change over time), the plugin will *still* be able to reach out
  // to the actual firebase.analytics() instance because the object will be overridden once the
  // firebase-analytics.js library is loaded in.
  firebase.analytics = function () {
    return {
      mock: true,
      app: function () {
        var instance = firebase.analytics()
        // Prevent infinite recursion if the real instance has not yet been loaded.
        if (instance.mock === true) return
        return instance.app
      },
      logEvent: function () {
        var instance = firebase.analytics()
        if (instance.mock === true) return
        return instance.logEvent(...arguments)
      },
      setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled: function () {
        var instance = firebase.analytics()
        if (instance.mock === true) return
        return instance.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(...arguments)
      },
      setCurrentScreen: function () {
        var instance = firebase.analytics()
        if (instance.mock === true) return
        return instance.setCurrentScreen(...arguments)
      },
      setUserId: function () {
        var instance = firebase.analytics()
        if (instance.mock === true) return
        return instance.setUserId(...arguments)
      },
      setUserProperties: function () {
        var instance = firebase.analytics()
        if (instance.mock === true) return
        return instance.setUserProperties(...arguments)
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```